# load dynamic data into table with multiple rows

Tags: java, jsp

EDIT:
I need to display dynamic data onto a table with multiple rows using JSP.I want this table to display 2 rows,1 row of columns on category and 1 row of columns on content.I have an example source code below,but it is not displaying in the correct format.How should I amend the codes to display in the correct format?

```
<%
String userName = (String)request.getSession().getAttribute("screenName");
ArrayList<String> stringList = (ArrayList<String>)request.getSession().getAttribute("stringList");
%>
<table id="table" border="1" align="center">
<tr>
<td align="center">
Category of Tweets:
</td>
<td align="center">
All Tweets of User: <%out.println(userName); %>
</td>
</tr>
<%
for(int i=0;i<stringList.size();i++){
%>
<tr>
<td>
<%
if(i%2==0){
String category = stringList.get(i).toString();
out.print(category);
%>
</td>
<%}else{ %>
<td>
<%
String content = stringList.get(i).toString();
out.print(content);
}
%>
</td>
</tr>
<%
}
%>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you actually mean by "The problem that I am facing now is that I cannot get the table to display those data correctly." Can you, please, be a little more specific about what's going wrong?

Comment: Any reason why you are using scriplets in you JSP? It's just a bad practice.

Comment: @Gamb What I meant was the output was not displaying the data in the correct rows.As in:Categories in the 1st row,and content in the 2nd row.

Comment: @BheshGurung I know it is bad practice,but I am not familiar with JSTL and right now I do not have sufficient time to learn.I have 2 days left to complete this.

Comment: IMO, you haven't anything (what the actual problem is and what the actual requirement is) yet in your question.

Comment: @BheshGurung I edited the post with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is simple, You are missing the second table column

You should have code to output blank column in both if and else....as below

I have tried to simplify the tag coding

```
<table id="table" border="1" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td align="center">
            Category of Tweets:
        </td>
        <td align="center">
            All Tweets of User: <%out.println(userName); %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <%
        for(int i=0;i<stringList.size();i++)
        {   
            String content = stringList.get(i).toString();          
            out.print("<tr>");
            if (i % 2 == 0) 
            {                                   
                out.print("<td>");
                out.print(content);
                out.print("</td>");
                out.print("<td></td>");
            }               
            else 
            {                       
                out.print("<td></td>");
                out.print("<td>");
                out.print(content);
                out.print("</td>");
            }
            out.print("</tr>"); 
        }   
    %>              
</table>
```

[image: This should produce something like this.....just as an example]

if you want to have the description come in the same row as category , use a seperate counter...

Hope this helps

Comment: Apparently it is still not displaying the table in the format I want.Could anybody else help?

Answer (score 0):

please look over the following points in your code

```
ArrayList<String> stringList = (ArrayList<String>)request.getSession().getAttribute("stringList");
%>
```

you are getting the session object again it is already available in jsp you can write session.getattribute

```
String category = stringList.get(i).toString();
```

you are again using the toString as the arraylist is of type string